# Is Archer's ringtone a real song outside the Archer universe?

Tags: sound-effects, archer

In the early seasons (1-3?), Archer uses a song for his ringtone that is just awful enough to be real, but I have never heard it anywhere else. Another character has the same song as a ring tone but with different words, possibly a different verse of the song.

Is this song an actual song from real-world pop culture, independent of Archer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No

[Mulatto Butts](https://archer.fandom.com/wiki/Mulatto_Butts) appears to be an original song made for the show, being characteristically offensive enough for Sterling Archer to use it as his ringtone. It appears to be somewhat based on the melody for [Spadina Bus by The Shuffle Demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shuffle_Demons).